# jQuery- Can not get one element to equal the height of another (jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a vertical list to the left of the content associated with that list item (vertical tabs). I am using jQuery to find the height of the largest "tab content", and make the ul equal that height, because there is a 1px border on the right side of the ul and I want it to line up with he content. However, the taller the height of the content gets, the more deficient the height of the ul is.

Here is a photo:

[image: example]

(the 1px right border of the ul should be the same height of the content)

And here is the jsfiddle showing what's going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/jM4F5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var tallest = $('#tatab-container ul').height(); // Minimum height is default ul height

$('#tamain-container p').each(function() {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(thisHeight > tallest) {
        tallest = thisHeight; // Modify to height of tallest paragraph
    }
});

$('#tatab-container ul').css('height', tallest); // Update ul height

});
```

When I use an alert to see what jQuery has, it returns the same height for the ul as well as the paragraph, but if so, why is the ul shorter?

Comment: You get the height of the `p` then change the height of the `ul`. Since the `ul` is higher, there is more *shorter* lines in the `p`, expending it more. Set a width to the `p` and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the `<ul>` structurally when that is really what your container `<div>`'s are for. Try something like this: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jM4F5/4/)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var tatabcont = $('#tatab-container');
    var tamaincont = $('#tamain-container');
    var tallest = tatabcont.height();
    if (tamaincont.height() > tallest) { tallest = tamaincont.height(); }
    tatabcont.height(tallest + "px");
    tamaincont.height(tallest + "px");
});

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#tatab-container {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
}
#tamain-container {
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
#tatab-container ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#tatab-container ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**Revision:** updated jQuery with `.resize()` : [**UPDATED JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jM4F5/6/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).resize(function(){ equalHeight(); });
    equalHeight();
});

function equalHeight() {
    var tatabcont = $('#tatab-container');
    var tamaincont = $('#tamain-container');
    tatabcont.css("height","auto"); // reset container height to natural
    tamaincont.css("height","auto"); // reset container height to natural
    var tallest = tatabcont.height();
    if (tamaincont.height() > tallest) { tallest = tamaincont.height(); }
    tatabcont.height(tallest + "px");
    tamaincont.height(tallest + "px");
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. Almost there. Now the only problem is if the browser is resized, the ul height is not updated.

Comment: you will need to add a `$(window).resize(...);` to the jQuery: see updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jM4F5/5/)

Comment: i also had to add the two lines with `.css("height","auto")` to reset the `<div>` heights to natural heights before re-sizing (this is needed for the `.resize()` event). **here is the newly updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jM4F5/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because when you adjust the height of the `<ul>`, you push the `<p>` content down further again. You need to set a specific width on the `<p>` element, so the math calculating in `.height()` is correct.

Some small CSS like:

```
#tamain-container {
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jM4F5/3/

Answer (score 0):

could you try with this code, you will adjust the height of shorter to taller one.

```
jQuery(function($) {
var tallest = $('#tamain-container p').height();
var short = $('#tatab-container ul').height();
if(tallest > short){
    $('#tatab-container ul').css('height',tallest);
}
 if(tallest < short){
    $('#tamain-container p').css('height',short);
}

});

 #tamain-container {float:left;width:55%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jM4F5/19/

Answer (score -1):

I would use css display:table to acheieve this. Something like this

```
<div style='display:table;border-collapse:collapse;'>
<div style='display:table-row'>
    <div style='display:table-cell;border-right:1px solid#000;'>// UL Navigation</div>
    <div style='display:table-cell'>//All Tabs content</div>
</div>
```

The table cells will always be of the same height and so will the border.